# SleekXMPP and Flask Socketio Hanging Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, flask-socketio, sleekxmpp

I'm trying to create and XMPP client that I can control from my browser. I'm using SleekXMPP for the XMPP client and flask-socketio for the website so I can relay information from the XMPP server to my XMPP client to my website frontend. If I used pure flask, I would need to poll my server for additional updates which I would rather have the server push to my client.

I am having some issues with threads. Connecting to the server works fine. But when I disconnect, I get an error showing that 3 threads cannot be killed. How can I kill these threads on disconnect? Or why are they not being killed? Or is there a better setup I should be using?

Thanks!!

The error:

```
DEBUG    Event triggered: session_end
DEBUG    Waiting for 3 threads to exit.
DEBUG    Finished exiting event runner thread after early termination from disconnect() call. 3 threads remain.
DEBUG    Finished exiting send thread after early termination from disconnect() call. 3 threads remain.
DEBUG    Quitting Scheduler thread
DEBUG    Finished exiting scheduler thread after early termination from disconnect() call. 3 threads remain.
ERROR    Hanged threads: [<_MainThread(MainThread, started 140735076622336)>, <Thread(read_thread, started 4452692848)>, <Thread(Thread-1, started daemon 4454843728)>]
ERROR    This may be due to calling disconnect() from a non-threaded event handler. Be sure that event handlers that call disconnect() are registered using: add_event_handler(..., threaded=True)
DEBUG    Event triggered: disconnected
DEBUG     ==== TRANSITION connected -> disconnected
```

Here is my python script.

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, disconnect
import sleekxmpp
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(levelname)-8s %(message)s')


class XMPPClient(sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP):

    def __init__(self, full_jid, pwd):

        self.full_jid = full_jid
        self.pwd = pwd
        sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP.__init__(self, self.full_jid, self.pwd)
        self.HOST = "XXX"
        self.PORT = "XXX"

    def conn(self):
        self.connect(address=(self.HOST, self.PORT))
        self.process(threaded=True)

    def disconn(self):
        self.disconnect(wait=True, send_close=False)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('socket_connect', namespace='/vibe')
def _socket_connect():
    xmpp_client.conn()
    return ""

@socketio.on('socket_disconnect', namespace='/vibe')
def _socket_disconnect():
    xmpp_client.disconn()
    return ""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    xmpp_client = XMPPClient(full_jid="XXX", pwd="XXX")
    socketio.run(app)
```

And for my frontend

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var socket

        $(document).ready(function(){
            namespace = '/vibe';
            socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);
        });

        function handle_connect(cmd) {
            socket.emit(cmd)
        } 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="handle_connect('socket_connect')">Connect</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="handle_connect('socket_disconnect')">Disconnect</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The logs that you get indicate what the problem is: `This may be due to calling disconnect() from a non-threaded event handler. Be sure that event handlers that call disconnect() are registered using: add_event_handler(..., threaded=True)`. It appears you can't freely stop the sleekxmpp freely from any code, you can only do it from a threaded event handler. Maybe it is as simple as starting a separate thread and running disconnect from there.